# Problema al leer el sitemap [No se ha podido obtener]

Tags: xml, google-search-console, sitemap

Llevo un tiempo tratando de hacer que mi sitio web sea visible en los motores de búsqueda de Google mediante sitemap pero la consola de google me tira el error **No se ha podido leer el sitemap**. ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?
Link del sitemap: https://fowmovies.ml/sitemap.xml

Aquí les dejo unas imagenes del problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema con mi web [quienfue.click](https://quienfue.click/) intente hacer lo de la / pero no funcionó, además de investigar y que según es por la extensión del domminio ya que el mio es un .click, siendo que aún no hay soporte o reconocen de manera normal como en otras extensiones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola puedes probar agregando una "/" al final.
Este error es común, la consola de google no los reconoce. Te dejo un link donde se crean los sitemap automaticamente https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/
Si estas trabajando con wordpress te recomiendo el plugin YoastSeo, el te crea el sitemap automaticamente.

Por otro lado google no necesita del sitemap hoy en día para indexar sitios, y tampoco supone un factor de posicionamiento, es decir que la search console no reconozca el sitemap, no debería de suponer mayor inconveniente.

Si tu pagina no es indexada, es porque no cumple los requerimientos de google, te dejo un enlace en donde estan los requerimientos de google https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184?hl=en